# DB2 Coalesce function is returning nulls

Tags: sql, db2, coalesce

I am using DB2 for IBM i V6R1, and I am trying to convert a string value which sometimes has a valid representation of a number in it into a number.  What I came up with was this:

```
select onorno, onivrf, coalesce(cast(substr(onivrf,1,5) as numeric),99999) as fred
from oinvol
```

sometimes the ONIVRF field has data like '00111-11', sometimes it has data like 'FREIGHT'.

The documentation leads me to believe that for data like this:

```
ONORNO ONIVRF
12     11010-11
13     FREIGHT
14     00125-22
```

I should get output like this:

```
ONORNO ONIVRF    FRED
12     11010-11  11010
13     FREIGHT   99999
14     00125-22  125
```

instead, I am getting this:

```
ONORNO ONIVRF    FRED
12     11010-11  11010
13     FREIGHT   NULL
14     00125-22  125
```

(If I skip the `coalesce()` and just use the `Cast(substr(onivrf(1,5) as numeric)`, I get exactly the same results.)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting an error attempting to cast 'FREIG' to numeric.

Comment: I'm running on the same platform, but I'm not getting `null`, I'm getting the 'replacement character' (which is `+` - null is indicated with a `-`).  There's also other behaviour related to this (`IS NULL` doesn't work, for example) that leads me to believe that I'm getting back what amounts to a `NaN` result for the operation... somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have mentioned that I tried spelling out "CASE when X is null" and "ifnull(x,etc)" and got the same behavior.  It still shows up in my output as a null.  Perhaps it's a 'feature' of my client software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to get rid of `ONIVRF`s that are all alphabetic characters, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ONORNO, ONIVRF, 
    CASE 
        WHEN UCASE(SUBSTR(ONIVRF,1,5)) = LCASE(SUBSTR(ONIVRF,1,5)) THEN CAST(SUBSTR(ONIVRF,1,5) AS NUMERIC)
        ELSE 99999
    END AS fred
FROM OINVOL
```

It's a little hackish, because DB2 doesn't have a `ISNUMERIC()` equivalent.  But alphabetic characters are the only ones that will be translated by the up- and lower-case functions.

I tested this on DB2 for z/OS (v9), and it worked, but I'm not sure if DB2 for iSeries is exactly the same.  On mine, it did as @Joe Stefanelli said, and raised an error when it tried to cast an alphabetic string to `NUMERIC`.

**Edit:**

This might work better (assuming that you won't have any `ONIVRF`s that are all tildes).  It shouldn't have the problem that @X-Zero mentions where some characters in languages other than English don't have lower and upper-case.

```
SELECT ONORNO, ONIVRF,
    CASE
        WHEN TRANSLATE(ONIVRF, '~~~~~~~~~~~', '0123456789-') = '~~~~~~~~' THEN CAST(SUBSTR(ONIVRF,1,5) AS NUMERIC)
        ELSE 99999
    END AS fred
FROM OINVOL
```

Comment: However (I just recalled) that not all alphabetic characters (in some scripts/languages) don't make a distinction between upper and lower case, so this isn't completely portable.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great.  I'm not too worried about alternate character sets, we're strictly English-speaking here.  :-)  Now I just have to figure out what to do when ONIVRF is an empty string (but not NULL).

Comment: You could add another part to the `CASE`:  `WHEN ONIVRF = '' THEN something`.  Otherwise, it should fall down into the `ELSE`...