# DB2 Case/Cast in Where statement

Tags: database, casting, db2, case, where-clause

The following query (slimmed down) has a string that needs to be cast into an Integer, but not all of the entries in that field have a value. The cast/case to int works fine in the select portion of the statement, but when in the where statement it fails. I am helping a co-worker and keep drawing a blank why this won't work. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT cast((case when item = ' ' then 0 else item end) as  int) as newNumber 
FROM tablename 
WHERE cast(trim(case when item = ' ' then 0 else item end) as INT) < 600
```

Here is the error

```
Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function DECFLOAT
```

The error only is thrown when the the **WHERE** statement is added.

Comment: The error message suggests that `item` contains non-numeric data which you are trying to convert to an integer.  I have played around with this quite a bit and couldn't find a case in which adding the `WHERE` clause would make it fail.  Are you sure that this exact statement will run without an error: `SELECT cast((case when item = ' ' then 0 else item end) as  int) as newNumber 
FROM tablename`?

Comment: Another test to make if my first suggestion doesn't reveal an error: `SELECT cast(trim(case when item = ' ' then 0 else item end) as INT) FROM tablename`.  Does this work or fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB2 Coalesce function is returning nulls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526442/db2-coalesce-function-is-returning-nulls)

Comment: However that question does not mention UDF which is probably the best way for all cases but could be slow.

Comment: I am positive the query runs correctly without the WHERE statement.  Very Strange.

Comment: I just talked with me co-worker. They got the query working with this statement....SELECT item FROM tablename  WHERE item < '600' . They put quotes around the number as if it was a string and the results were correct. How can that be? That can't be proper execution.

Comment: Because character `'1'` is less than character `'6'`, on every system I'm aware of.  Your real problem is going to be that `'7'` will sort higher than `'600'`, unless you've padded it with blanks/zeroes (please see an [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aa98/1)).  **Why** are you storing numbers this way?

Comment: I am not storing it this way. It's an old old system and was set up ridiculously. They also have Null values and empty values in the field. It's a nightmare. I figured sorting would be the area where the problem would manifest itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  Q1 (ITEM) AS
     (VALUES ' ', '1', '2', '3', 'DFSDF', '601'),
  Q2 (ITEM) AS
     (SELECT INTEGER(CASE WHEN ITEM = ' ' THEN '0' ELSE ITEM END) AS NEWNUMBER
        FROM Q1
        WHERE TRIM(TRANSLATE(ITEM, '', '0123456789')) = '')
SELECT *
  FROM Q2
  WHERE Q2.ITEM < 600
```